# Website live: some clients get a 404 response. Why and where from?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I have a website on the web. Published and it's OK on most computers.

However, some computers always get a 404 response. Why?

I am no expert in what relates to networks and stuff but I imagined the domain would need more time to be spread all over the web. However, this is happening since 3 or 4 days ago.

I did a check worldwide and apparently all servers world wide in check were alright.

I did a dnsflush to no avail too.

I don't have the specific domain on my hosts file.

Can anyone please give some guidelines about what I have to do to narrow the problem?

Comment: First you should check if those errors actually appear in your server's log file. If they do, you know that at least the clients are hitting your server so a DNS problem is unlikely. If they don't, you know the clients are hitting the wrong server for one reason or another.

Comment: Thanks for guideline. Yes, I just checked event viewer and there are not errors for this site. So I guess something else is responding with a 404 somewhere else. It kind of makes sense because the resource is in the server. Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach the DNS issue?

Comment: Depends on if the DNS has updated or not with each ISP. Please note, they say it takes up to 72 hours but this is a ball park average. It can take days (depending on how often the ISP update their DNS records). Use this site to test your website http://www.intodns.com/

Comment: @FabioMilheiro Check **all** of the authoritative DNS servers for your domain to see if one of them might be out of sync and giving out incorrect A or AAAA records that point to an incorrect server. It could be that one of your slaves is not getting updates from the master. To query each name server directly, use `dig @x.y.z.w domain.org. a` and `dig @x.y.z.w domain.org. aaaa` where x.y.z.w is the IP address of the name server.